# Custom Share Buttons Supporting VCard and Opengraph

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-opengraph, social-media, twitter-card

I am trying to add CUSTOM share buttons to my website for Twitter and Facebook. Is using sharer.php for Facebook appropriate still? How would I pass the Open Graph data? As for Twitter, how would I pass the Twitter Card data? I typically use Addthis.com plugin but it is not appropriate for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish implementing sharing functionality by using the following:

Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Twitter https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button

The facebook share dialog automatically pulled the Open Graph data from the page.